# Excluding multiple modules by groupID

Tags: maven, plugins

I am trying to create third party license report for my component and I need to excluded few artifacts based on their groupIds. I can successfully do it for a single groupId but not able to do this for multiple groupdIds. How can this be done.

> mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true  license:aggregate-add-third-party license:aggregate-download-licenses -Dlicense.excludedGroups="com.test.*","com.test2.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research and trial and error attempts I figured out how to do this.

```
       ` <plugin>
            <groupId>testgroupdid</groupId>
            <artifactId>testartifactID</artifactId>
            <version>${license-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludedScopes>test</excludedScopes>
                <excludedGroups>test.group1.*|test.group2.*</excludedGroups>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>`
```